# Submit null object with FormBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript

If a get an object from backend API service like:

`data: {firstName:'pepe',lastName:'test', address = {street: 'Cervantes', city:'Villajoyosa'} }
or data: {firstName:'pepe',lastName:'test', address = null }`

I want to set the object in the formGroup, but I have a problem when address comes null, I want to save address as null not as {street: '', city:''}}

```
     form = this.fb.group({
            firstName: [''],
            lastName: [''],
            address: this.fb.group({
              street: [''],
              city: [''],
            }),
          });
    // and I set the form:
    if(data.address)
    this.form.controls['address'].setValue(data.address)
save(){
valueToSend = this.form.controls['address'].getValue()
}
// template
<button (click)=save()>Save</button>
    <div formGroupName="address">
      <h3>Address</h3>
      <label>
        Street:
        <input type="text" formControlName="street">
      </label>
      <label>
        City:
        <input type="text" formControlName="city">
      </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to share the code that sets the values in the form with the data

Comment: You could use `*ngIf`, example:  `<div formGroupName="address" *ngIf="data.address">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't worry about the form until you save data. In submit

```
save()
{
  const data={...this.form.value,address:...this.form.value.address} //<--create a copy
  if (!data.address.city && !data.address.street)
  {
       data.address=null;
  }
  ..make something with the data..
  myService.update(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck with the form structure that you've defined so you're forced to have some transformation logic when you submit the form.

For example:

```
const { firstName, lastName, address } = this.form;
const value = {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    address: address.street || address.city ? address : null
};
```

You can also encapsulate this logic in a component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`, like in the following example:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-address",
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="form">
      <input formControlName="street" />
      <input formControlName="city" />
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AddressComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      street: [""],
      city: [""]
    });
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.form.setValue(obj);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(map(x => x.city || x.street ? x : null)).subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    //TODO
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

Working demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2uzcn)

Comment: And how would you implement the form structure to avoid that logic? Regards

Comment: I've provided a cleaner solution to your problem